# turtle setworldcoordinates couldn't find reference intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, turtle-graphics

I ran someone's code from GitHub on intellij and it worked.
But I have some problems with it.

For example:

```
import turtle
..
def main():
..
turtle.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, xsize, ysize)
```

[image]

intellij says that it couldn't find reference (to this function) in turtle.py, so
I tried to get rid of it, so I wrote

```
import turtle
..
def main():
..
turtle.TurtleScreen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, xsize, ysize)
```

which is the right path, but now it says that he wants type TurtleScreen.
I'm missing something here.

intellij says that he can't find the reference, what does it mean exactly, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Just checking: you don't have a file named `turtle.py` in your directory, do you? Giving a file the same name as a built-in module can lead to all sorts of confusing problems.

Comment: No, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more of the original code, I can't tell you why:

```
turtle.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, xsize, ysize)
```

didn't work, it should have.  But I can tell you why this won't work:

```
turtle.TurtleScreen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, xsize, ysize)
```

it's because you're invoking an instance method as a class method and `self` is missing.  My preferred way to approach the turtle module is:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, xsize, ysize)
...
yertle = Turtle()
...
screen.exitonclick()
```

But in your case you could try:

```
turtle.Screen().setworldcoordinates(0, 0, xsize, ysize)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm lost in the GUI hierarchy. Do you know maybe a good place to dive into it? most of the tutorials online are too easy. And the documentation is very hard for someone that never dealt with GUI...